# How do I use awk split file to multiline records?

Tags: awk

On OSX, I've converted a Powerpoint deck to ASCII text, and now want to process this with awk.

- I want to split the file into multiline records corresponding to slides in the deck.
- Treating any line beginning with a capital latin letter provides a good approximation, but I can't figure out doing this in awk.
- I've tried resetting the record separator, `RS = "\n^[A-Z]"` and `RS = "\n^[[:alnum:]][[:upper:]]"`, and various permutations, but none differentiate.  That is, awk keeps treating each individual as a record, rather than grouping them as I want.

The cleaned text looks like this:

```
Welcome
++  Class will focus on:
–   Basics of SQL syntax
–   SQL concepts analogous to Excel concepts
Who Am I
++  Self-taught on LAMP(ython) stack
++  Plus some DNS, bash scripting, XML / XSLT
++  Prior professional experience:
–   Office of Management and Budget
–   Investment banking (JP Morgan, UBS, boutique)
–   MBA, University of Chicago


Roadmap
+   Preliminaries
+   What is SQL
+   Excel vs SQL
+   Moving data from Excel to SQL and back
+   Query syntax basics
-   Running queries
-   Filtering, grouping
-   Functions
-   Combining tables
+   Using queries for analysis
```

Some 'slides' have blank lines, some don't.

Once past these hurdles I plan to wrap each record in an  tag for use in deck.js.  But getting the record definitions right is killing me.

How do I do those things?

EDIT: The question initially asked also about converting Unicode bullet characters to ASCII, but I've figured that out.  Some remarks in comments focus on that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk` you could try to collect records using:

```
/^[[:upper:]]/ {
    if (r>0) print rec 
    r=1; rec=$0 RS;    next
}
{  
    rec=rec $0 RS 
}

END {
    print rec
}
```

To remove bullets you could use

```
gsub (/•/,"++",rec)
```

Comment: I don't know how to the bullet character to the command line, BUT have found a solution to that (and will add to my question).  Please either explain how to get the bullet to command line, or delete that piece, so the answer is unambiguous.  I'm looking at the other piece now.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "to the command line"? Maybe you could you give a sample input file, such that it is clear what is to be processed with `awk`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the line at the bottom of the vi screen in Command Mode -- the line starting w/ :.  I don't know how to get a character in text to appear in commands in command mode.

Comment: so the piece on record splitting seems a step in the right direction, but it is only outputting every other block of text

Comment: Why can we not just change the bullets to `++` within the `awk` program?

Comment: Probably could have.  Wasn't sure of feasability.  Also, file needs some manual editing to get bullet indentations right.

Comment: Thanks, for the sample output. The `awk` code works fine with me on the sample you gave..

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the "textutil" utility built into OSX to convert the file within a script to save you doing it all by hand. Try typing the following into Terminal window and pressing  to move to the next page:

```
man textutil
```

Once you have got some converted text, try posting that so people can see what the inputs look like, then maybe someone can help you split it up how you want.